# How to pad left in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, pad

I'm new to Rust and completely lost in the standard library. I do not want to add a crate just for padding.
How do I pad left a number with zeroes up to a certain width?

Lets say I have this code and I need the pad_left implementation.

```
fn main() {
  let i = 5.to_string();

  let padded_i = pad_left(i, 2);
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. We can close this as duplicate

Answer (score 4):

The [Rust Docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#sign0) has an example of how you could format a number as a string with leading zeroes up to a certain width (5 in this example):

```
format!("Hello {:05}!", 5); // returns, "Hello 00005!"
format!("Hello {:05}!", -5); // returns, "Hello -0005!"
```

If you need to print the number, then you can replace the `format!` macro with `print!` or `println!` instead.

Comment: And what if I want to pad a str "a" with 'b's ?

Comment: See the section directly above the one I linked to in my solution: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#fillalignment

Comment: @ditoslav `println!("{:b>5}", "a");` will give you `bbbba`